# What is this tree I found in Mississippi?

Tags: identification, trees, leaves

I moved to northeastern Mississippi and found this tree in my backyard. What is it?
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it is a pear:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pear

---

(Also, when trying to post only necessary and sufficient information for a response, I was confusingly told: "Body must be at least 30 characters")

Comment: Thanks! That seems right. Any idea of what type?

Comment: Well...definitely not Bradford Pear.  While not exactly sure, I think it just looks like your standard fruit pear tree.  Partridge not included...